# Comparing the 1st column of N files, if match found print the 1st file and 2nd column of remaining files

Tags: python, perl, awk

I have a numbers of files each having two columns and want to compare the files with 1st column. if match found in all files, print the 1st file and 2nd column of remaining files.

Input Example

## File 1

```
 apple    tree
 great    see
 see      apple
 tree     bee
 make     change
```

## File 2

```
great    2
see      3
tree     4
make     5
```

## File 3

```
apple    10  
great    9
see      8
tree     7
```

Expected Output

```
 great    see     2     9
 see      apple   3     8
 tree     bee     4     7
```

I am able to do only with two files. using

```
 awk  'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$0; next}; $1 in a {print a[$1]}' file1 file2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If first column in all your files consist of unique values this should do the trick:

```
$ awk '{a[$1]=a[$1]"\t"$2} ++n[$1]==3{print $1 a[$1]}' file1 file2 file3
great   see     2       9
see     apple   3       8
tree    bee     4       7
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [join](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/join.1.html):

```
$ join <(sort file1) <(sort file2) | join - <(sort file3)
great see 2 9
see apple 3 8
tree bee 4 7
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following(this will take care of sequence of 1st field too in which sequence they are occurring they will come in output).

```
awk '
!c[$1]++{
  d[++count]=$1
}
{
  a[$1]++
  b[$1]=(b[$1]?b[$1] OFS:"")$NF
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    if(a[d[i]]==3){
       print d[i],b[d[i]]
    }
  }
}
'  file1 file2 file3  | column -t
```